# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView with 2 columns right align not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am trying to get a ListView with 2 columns with a Textblock in each. I like the second textblock to align right against the right side of the screen. Sadly the Name and Amount just sit next to eachother and are both aligned left. My Xaml look like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
    <ListView Name="OverviewListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle }" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle }"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How do I get the second column to align left and both columns together to use the full width of the screen?